# Julia implementation of mul! when Y = A?

Tags: matrix, julia, matrix-multiplication, memory-efficient

Matrix multiplication Y = A * B can be implemented by mul!(Y, A, B) to save on memory allocations. But mul! can't be used if Y = A. Is there a similarly efficient way to calculate Y *= B? Or if not, what is the most efficient way to do matrix multiplication Y *= B

Small working example:

```
n = 10
A = rand(n,n)
B = rand(n,n)
Y = zeros(n,n)

#mul! removes allocations 
@allocated Y = A * B   #896
@allocated mul!(Y, A, B) #0    

#mul! can't be applied in this case
@allocated Y *= B #896

#desired function performance
@allocated mul_2!(Y, B)  #0
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can implement this efficiently (due to how blocking in matrix multiplication works). You're better off just keeping around another matrix of the appropriate size to use as a buffer.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful!
As a note for future users, if you have a for loop and you want to implement this you can implement this by 

for i = 1:(i_max)
    if i % 2 = 0
       mul!(Y1, Y0, B_i)
    else 
       mul!(Y0, Y1, B_i)
    end
end

where B_i is whatever matrix needs to be added for the relevant iteration

Answer (score 1):

Although it is hard to do without any allocations, as other answer explained. Reducing the allocations to O(n) instead of O(n^2) is possible by decomposing the matrix multiply into a series of independant vector-matrix multiplies. So `mul_2!` would look something like this:

```
function mul_2!(Y, B)
    tmprow = Matrix{eltype(Y)}(undef,1,size(Y,2))
    foreach(eachrow(Y)) do r
        mul!(tmprow, r', B) 
        r .= tmprow'
    end
end
```

and the output for call in OP:

```
julia> @allocated mul_2!(Y, B)  # 144 instead of 0 ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
144
```

And to get allocations all the way down to zero, the temporary vector can be passed as a parameter to `mul_2!` and pre-allocated. Which means if repeating operation many times, no allocations will happen during calculations.

Something along the line of:

```
tmprow = Matrix{eltype(Y)}(undef,1,size(Y,2))
for i in 1:lots_of_iterations
    mul_2_notmp!(Y,B,tmprow)
end
```

In terms of speed, allocations are slow, so no allocations is better. But the exact trade-offs should depend on matrix sizes, as the standard matrix multiplication library has gone through a ton of optimization.

Comment: increasing to 8xn is probably a better tradeoff since it will allow for much better use of vectorization.